# how do i match the corresponding cell values between different sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

How do i auto update sheet 2 column B such that when corresponding values are added in column B of sheet 1.

[image: updated USERID of chicken in sheet 1]

[image: USERID of chicken is auto updated in sheet 2]

Comment: Are you looking for [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)?

Comment: @idfurw ive redited my qn to make it more coherent. I tried the vlookup but i am still unable to do it. Could you kindly guide me through this as I am new to google sheets and is struggling :,(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in cell `'Sheet2'!B2`:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A,Sheet1!A2:B,2,FALSE)),"")
```

#### References:

- [IFERROR - Google Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA - Google Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [VLOOKUP - Google Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)

Comment: it says that" Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B3." so im not sure what went wrong

Comment: Delete the rest of the data in column B

Comment: I think `IFNA` is better than `IFERROR`. If say the sheet of the range is deleted, you cannot know it with `IFERROR`. `IFNA` would show you `#REF!`.

Comment: Thanks! it works well now. However i am curious, what if i already have values in in the other rows in the same column like previously. Bc i have already applied a formula to filter the names without userID from sheet 2 to sheet 1.